# How to get Access to this nested value from Firebase Database in a String Variable?

Tags: android, firebase

Here is my FirebaseDatabase Structure.

[image: Firebase Database]

> How can I access this "1" value from firebase database (Image at Top)

Comment: post your push method cdoe.

Comment: its manual from Console @AbhayKoradiya

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Alert");
        Log.e("ALERTS HERE -> ",databaseReference.toString());

Comment: Please post code in your question, not in comments - it's too hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get the value of your `alerts` property would be:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference alertsRef = rootRef.child("Alert").child("1").child("alerts");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long alerts = dataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(alerts));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
alertsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be:

```
1
```

So in order to get a value of a Firebase record, you need to make a `child()` call for every children in the tree. In a more simpler manner you can also use:

```
DatabaseReference alertsRef = rootRef.child("Alert/1/alerts");
```

Comment: ok , i got this error :   Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String.  how can 1 be a long data type ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Please see my updated answer. It should work now. Just changed String to Long.

Answer (score -1):

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("elon**").child("Alert").child("1").child("alert").child("1").setValue(xxxxx)